# Automatic update

Tags: upgrade, scripts, unattended-upgrades

I want to set up an Ubuntu laptop for a person with 0 experience of linux and who does not want to learn more than just use a few programs (replacement for Windows for an older family member; she really likes ubuntu, finds it easy enough to use, and snappy :) ).

I want to make sure all updates are applied. I am aware of (and have enabled / set up for full update once a day) `unattended-upgrades`. However, I am worried that if the laptop is mostly being used for quite short amounts of time and conscientiously shut off, the upgrades may not be applied by the unattended thing.

- Is this worry based on reality? Does `unattended-upgrades` attempt to upgrade immediately when the laptop is turned on (does not seem so as I still get quite a lot installed with `apt` each time I switch it on, though `unattended-upgrades` is set up), or does it do it only 'once a day at 01.00 am' or something like that, in which case it may never be called?
- Would calling this kind of script from the root crontab (ie adding an `@reboot bash script_update.sh` to `sudo crontab -e`) help? :

```
#!/bin/bash

# A little script to:
#   - wait that internet is available
#   - wait for the automatic software update to be finished running
#   - apply the apt-get update and upgrade to the system
# This means that updates are installed automatically without
# asking confirmation. This should be ok for most vanilla uses.
#
# SETUP
#
# set the XX_SET_PATH to the log file
#
# To make it run automatically, put it in crontab:
# sudo crontab -e
# and in the root crontab that gets opened:
# @reboot bash PATH_TO_THE_SCRIPT.sh

function check_online
{
    netcat -z -w 5 8.8.8.8 53 && return 1 || return 0
}

function wait_online
{
    echo "wait to be online"
    declare -i IS_ONLINE=0

    while [ $IS_ONLINE -eq 0 ]; do
        # We're offline. Sleep for a bit, then check again
        sleep 2;
        check_online
        IS_ONLINE=$?
    done

    echo "now online"
}

{
    echo " "
    echo "new reboot"
    date
    whoami
    wait_online
    echo "wait for 20 minutes to make sure no conflicting catch of dpkg lock"
    sleep 1200
    echo "now start update upgrade..."
    apt-get update
    apt-get upgrade -y
    apt-get autoremove
} >> XX_SET_PATH 2>&1
```

Comment: Tell the user to leave it running overnight once in a while.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unattended Upgrades (UU) will attempt to run as soon as it's timer tells it to. If the system happens to be off when the timer expires, then UU will notice during boot and will run a couple minutes after boot.

- You DON'T need to add your own script. The UU developers anticipated this use case.

Your own use case ("*I still get quite a lot installed with apt*") occurs when folks are updating from multiple pockets: -security, -updates, third party repos, etc. UU's default settings are to use -security only. You can change those settings if you wish, but it's usually unnecessary for casual users.

- You DON'T need to change UU setting to match your usage. The default settings seem to suit the anticipated usage of the user that you envision.

Firefox and other web browsers that are distributed by Ubuntu (i.e. not Chrome) are updated through the -security pocket. This means that your user will always have the safest browser version available via UU.

Advice: It's probably wise to set up your casual user on an LTS release, to reduce the amount of support you must provide.

Comment: Also, add the molly-guard package http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/molly-guard.8.html and put a physical molly-guard https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/molly-guard over the power button

Comment: Many thanks, this is the kind of info I had been looking for in a long time :)

Comment: Not sure why I should do this @K7AAY? I understand the software molly-guard to avoid intempestive reboots due to updates (?), but not the physical one. I still want that the laptop can be started ^^ .

Comment: Make them think twice about turning the system _off_ instead of properly running shutdown. If you teach them just to turn off the screen (or closing it for a laptop) instead of powering off, and the molly guard is in place, you will get fewer puzzled calls from them.

Comment: Yah, you know @K7AAY people who were born in the 40s / 50s / up to 60s really like to turn stuff off to save electricity at least around me ^^ . They even claim they see the impact of just having bought a new computer on the electricity bill. Living very frugally I guess...

Comment: @Zorglub29 Boomers OK! I identify as a Boomer, and I appreciate the concept. Maybe explaining how economical modern CPUs are when they idle may help, along with the suggestion to turn off the screen/close the lid, as the display consumes a lot of juice, might suffice?